# Regular expression for email address with only lowercase letters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for email address AND lowercase letters only. Could anyone help a newbie? I tried some regex editors, but just not getting it to work.

```
Example input:
John@test.org (not allowed)
JOHN@test.com (not allowed)
john-test.com (not allowed)
john@test.com (allowed)
john@test.org (allowed)
```

Answer (score 2):

[this](https://regex101.com/r/m3SuQg/1) should work:

```
^[a-z]+\@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `^[a-z]+\@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$`

to Javascript: `/^[a-z]+\@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$/g`

to Python: `r"^[a-z]+\@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$"`

to Ruby: `/^[a-z]+\@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$/`